# How to get true full width modules in Cassiopeia?

Tags: joomla-4

In the Joomla 4! default template Cassiopeia, I can choose between Static and Fluid layouts.

Static Layouts give me nice margins around the content, and makes the website have a more 'boxed' layout, like so:

[image: static layout]

But if I choose the fluid layout, it still looks 'boxed' because the background colour of the site shows up arond the tops and sides of my module:

[image: fluid module]

Even adding a full-width module suffix doesn't seem to do anything. How do I break out of this boxed layout and create a full width module, like the footer, inside the 'site grid'?